# Where should I connect my ceiling fan's blue wire?

Tags: electrical

I want to install a new fan and light assembly. I removed the old one, which on the wall is a hard wired 2 switch, one for the fan and one for the lights. Coming out of the ceiling is a white, black and copper wire. I understand black to black, white to white and green to copper wire. This unit also has a blue wire for lights. Not sure where to attach this blue wire. I tried to put it with the other 2 black wires but that does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: How was the old fan wired?

Comment: AS said in other comments a black, white, and bare copper wire at the ceiling box are only enough wires to control one switched circuit. That could be wired fan-only or light-only or fan+light together. If that second switch on the wall is turning on and off a light are you sure it is not controlling a separate light in the room? Another question....Did the old fan have an integrated light that turned on and off with the fan and not separately by itself? Lastly you may want to look closely in the ceiling box to make sure that the there is not a third alternately colored wire that broke off.

Comment: Scott, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) and either accept an answer, provide and accept an answer of your own, or delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

Black and blue from the fan go together

Comment: Fist turn off the switch. test for power to be off. hook black and blue to the same wire, you don't have 2 switches do you? both fan and light will come on at the same time. 2 switches would mean the blue wire goes to the other switch.

Comment: Why would someone give you a demerit on this? Yes, the black and blue go from the fan will tie together if you only have one switch to control the entire unit. You'll use the pull chains if you only want to run the fan or the light, but the switch will control power to both. If you have more than one switchleg up there in the ceiling, which you apparently do not, you would tie one to the blue and one to the black.

Comment: I have two separate switches on the wall. One controls the fan, the other controls the light (can be dimmed).

Comment: If you tried all the wires either the light is off at the fan pull chain or the second switch does not go to the fan. It should be simple. If you took down the old one, it should be the same wiring, and both switches should work. If the other wires were tied together it means the switch is also controlling something else like an outlet

Comment: The other possibility is a bad switch. A tester would remove all guesswork. Flip the switch on and off test until you identify the wires attached to the switches. If all the other wires are black I don't know how else to help.

Comment: @Scott, black, white and bare copper in the ceiling does not give you enough wires to control both light and fan independently. There are remote wireless kits you can install to do this if you want or you could add another wire from your switch location to the ceiling box. From what you've said you have at the ceiling it isn't possible for the two separate hard wired switches ever worked to control fan and light separately.

Comment: Is there a red wire by chance?

Comment: Lol. I had an electrician check it out. Apparently the old owners jerry rigged it and I’m lucky it did not start a fire. They had tied in the ground copper wire to the white wires. Thanks everybody for you’re input

Comment: The purpose of comments on SE Q&A websites is to help someone **improve** their Q or A. Comments are disposable. The aim is to build a library of Q's & As useful to future searchers. Please edit useful material into the answer.

Comment: @Scott you should go ahead and write that up as an answer and when it allows you to go ahead and accept it.  No one here guessed that, and it is a valid answer.

Comment: @Scott -- write that up as an answer, and I'll +1 it :) (and yes, it's not particularly rare to see that sort of thing happen, as production builders will do just about anything to pinch a penny or three)